# Как экранировать кавычки в Delphi?

Tags: delphi

В SQL Management Studio срабатывает запрос (корректно выполняется):

```
INSERT INTO testdata (field1, field2) VALUES ('12.05.2015', '5454')
```

В Delphi одинарные кавычки означают открытие и закрытие кода...
Так как написать строку следующую строку?

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO testdata (field1, field2) VALUES ('12.05.2015', '5454')');
```

Пробовал так:

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO testdata (field1, field2) VALUES ("12.05.2015", "5454")');
```

Не помогло.
В php экранировать можно кавычки, а в Delphi как быть с такими вещами?

Comment: Вам [сюда](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Using_Parameters_in_Queries)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В Delphi кавычки экранируются двойными значками кавычки, вот так:

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add(
  'INSERT INTO testdata (field1, field2) VALUES (''12.05.2015'', ''5454'')');
```

Что в результате даст вот такой текст запроса:

> INSERT INTO testdata (field1, field2) VALUES ('12.05.2015', '5454')

Comment: Спасибо большое! Как банально просто всё оказалось. Видели бы вы количество моих попыток в коде...
Сам же знал про такую штуку, но.... лет 5-7 не программировал на Delphi. Спасибо ещё раз.

Comment: А с переменной как-то громоздко получается:
`ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO testdata (field1, field2) VALUES ('+''''+DateToStr(now)+''''+', '+input_value+')');`

Comment: Обычно переменные передают через параметры, чтобы не получилось как в комиксе (http://www.drupal.ru/files/drop.png)

Answer (score 2):

Ответ дан, но все же дам небольшой совет. Используйте при написании запросов параметры. ADOQuery1.Parameters это позволит обезопасить код от ошибок и упростить работу с запросом.

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO testdata (field1, field2) VALUES (:p1, :p2)');
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('p1').value := '12.05.2015';
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('p2').value := '5454';
```

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, использование непосредственно операторов DML в коде - весьма непрофессионально и неправильно с точки зрения дизайна. Однако, вопрос был про кавычки. Отвечу на него.

*Экранирование кавычек* (как вы выразились) усложняет читаемость кода и затрудняет отладку приложения. Но если уж вы хардкодите DML в код, то я бы рекомедовал объявнить глобальную константу:

```
Q   = #39;
```

и использовать eё в "подстановках" под поля. Например:

```
s := 'update Users set IsActive = 0 where Username = ' + Q + Edit1.Text + Q;
```

Если использовать в коде хранимые процедуры (что намного правильнее, так как текст sp можно всегда поправить на стороне сервера), то там подстановка параметров будет еще изящнее. Надо лишь добавить еще несколько констант:

```
QCQ = #39#44#39;
QC  = #39#44;
CQ  = #44#39;
C   = #44;
```

Как вы догадываетесь, `Q` - это single quote, а `С` - это comma. Все остальные - это возможные сочетания, которые встретятся при передаче параметров разных типов в хранимую процедуру.

Строка вызова процедуры `myproc @i int, @v varchar(10), @c char(2)` на Delphi будет выглядеть вот так:

```
s := 'myproc ' + IntToStr(i) + cq + v + qcq + c + q;
```

DML – Data Manipulation Language. То есть низкоуровневые SQL-операторы манипулирования данными: update, insert, delete.

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста в тексте ответа, что такое DML.

Comment: *DML в коде - весьма непрофессионально и неправильно с точки зрения дизайна.* Можно подробнее про это?

Comment: @Nofate подробнее где? В комментарии или в ответе? Имхо, это будет дискуссия на другую тему. Отличную от темы вопроса.

Comment: Если совсем коротко, то хардкодинг DML в код влечет за собой необходимость перекомпиляции приложения при возникновении изменений. Любой хардкодинг (параметров, строк и пр.) – это существенный недостаток дизайна.

Answer (score 0):

Ещё вариант

```
 QuotedStr ( const S: string ): string;
```

Comment: Слишком короткий ответ, приведите хотя бы пример использования и результат )